# Grails - Logging SQL and get time elapsed

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

On a `Grails 2.2.2` app I'm using this code below  to log `SQL Queries`. I'd like to `log` the **time elapsed** for each queries is that possible and how to do it ?

Thank you

Config.groovy

```
log4j = {
    trace 'org.hibernate.type'
    debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'
    // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For grails 3 and above do the following.

1. In application.groovy

```
hibernate.generate_statistics = true
```

2. In logback.groovy

```
logger("org.hibernate.stat", DEBUG, ["STDOUT"], false)
```

For details please refer to [this](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-log-execution-time-query) article.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the [Java melody plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-melody) for Grails? It not only shows you the execution times of your SQL statements but also includes lots of other performance metrics regarding your application. It's a useful overview tool for monitoring and beginning performance investigations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Nice tool ! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can user [miniprofiler](http://grails.org/plugin/miniprofiler) plugin to see time and other useful information. This plugin shows numbers of DB hits per page and time to render the page.

`Shows timing and sql query information in a head-up display in a web page, useful for debugging database and other performance problems.`

Just add plugins in build config

```
runtime ':profiler:0.5'
runtime ':miniprofiler:0.3'
```

and

```
<miniprofiler:javascript/>
```

in your layout just before closing the body.

Hope this helps..,.

Answer (score -2):

try looking at:
http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1604

```
dataSource {
   dbCreate = ...
   url = ...
   ...
   logSql = true
}
```

and/or

```
log4j = {
   ...
   debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't give an answer to the question. I want to log the time elapsed for each queries.

Comment: I found log4jdbc and a nice post about it & grails : http://bartling.blogspot.it/2011/09/tracing-and-profiling-sql-in-grails.html